# Change cell color of cell on next worksheet if checkbox is checked

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have an excel document with sheets representing information for each month. These sheets contain lists of members. On each sheet there are multiple checkboxes (about 250 per sheet). I would like to do the following.

Lets take months `September` and `October` as an example. if I check a checkbox on the `September`-sheet then the color of the same cell the checkbox is located (ex. `D23`) on the next sheet (in this case it would be `"October"`) should change to blue. If the same checkbox is being unchecked (even for example in the future) then the cell should turn red.

1. check checkbox on `'September'!D:23`
2. color on cell `D23` on the next sheet `October` turns blue
3. uncheck checkbox on `'September'!D:23`
4. color on cell `D23` on the next sheet `October` turns red

My way of solving the problem: I have written a `Sub` which, when a checkbox is created, it links the checkbox to the cell it was placed on (for example `D23`) so that I can know which cell needs to change when checked/unchecked on the next sheet:

```
.LinkedCell = Selection.Address(False, False)
```

This is what I've tried so far but with no success:

```
Sub SetMacro()
  Dim cb
  For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.OnAction = "" Then cb.OnAction = "CheckedUnchecked"
  Next cb
End Sub
```

and here is the code for the check/uncheck:

```
Sub CheckedUnchecked()
With ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).LinkedCell)
    If .Value Then
        Worksheet(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Range(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).LinkedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    Else
    Worksheet(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Range(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).LinkedCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Any thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worksheets have a `.Next` method that references the next worksheet in the worksheets collection.  If the worksheet is the last worksheet in the collection it will return nothing.

[image]

### Paste into a standard module

```
Sub CheckedUnchecked()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    With ActiveSheet
        Set cb = .CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
        If Not cb Is Nothing Then
            If .Next Is Nothing Then
                Worksheets("January").Range(cb.TopLeftCell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(cb.Value = 1, 5, 3)
            Else
                .Next.Range(cb.TopLeftCell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(cb.Value = 1, 5, 3)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: code works great with one exception, namely the month "November". "December" is the last sheet in this workbook but by some reason the cell color doesn't change if I check the checkboxes in "November"... any thoughts on this?

Comment: and another question: how did you make the "TRUE" or "FALSE" which appear after checking the checkbox unseen?

Comment: this code works great for the first two months but sadly not for the other months... do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Here is a link to the file. Please note that I annonimized names and titles but that should not stand in the way: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6v7lPApXN7mZjJjRWVvM3ZNdGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found the solution. I made a mistake by copying the sheet multiple times. By this the checkboxes had the same names on each sheet. After I inserted manually each cell on each sheet (avioding multiple checkboxes with same name) it worked.

Comment: @user3185735 I must have been busy I forgot to debug it.  I am glad that you finally got it.  Take Care

Answer (score 2):

**edited** NextMonthSht() to properly handle months *index* after 9

Here follows a slightly different solution to:

- allow for months sheets in any index order
- allow for any sheets name

Code:

```
Sub CheckedUnchecked()
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
        NextMonthSht.Range(.TopLeftCell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(.Value = 1, 5, 3)
    End With
End Sub

Function NextMonthSht() As Worksheet
    Const MONTHS As String = "January,February,March,April,Maj,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,January"

    Set NextMonthSht = Worksheets(Split(MONTHS, ",")(Len(Left(MONTHS, InStr(MONTHS, ActiveSheet.name))) - Len(Replace(Left(MONTHS, InStr(MONTHS, ActiveSheet.name)), ",", "")) + 1))
End Function
```

Comment: @ThomasInzina, thanks for noticing the two digits month issue. I handled it (still) avoiding the use of _Date_ functions to keep the "promised" feature of handling _"any sheets name"_

Comment: @ThomasInzina, thanks. I _could_ have used an array but I wouldn't to lessen the user input burden. While I don't get the "Worksheets (Month(ActiveSheet.name & " 1")) " thing

Comment: @ThomasInzina, still can't get what "Month(ActiveSheet.name & " 1")" is supposed to do. I'm not by my PC but it seems to me it should evaluate to something like "Month("January 1")" that can't figure out. Furthermore if "Month" is a 'Date' function than it'd still defeat my purpose of allowing any sheets names (not only month names).

Comment: @user3598756 same as the code above... it works for the first and the second worksheet but for the rest it doesn't work. Do I need to paste the code in the VBA Module "This Workbook"? Or should I just paste it in a random module and it will work automatically?